# Generating terrain around structure in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

is there any program/server plugin/etc that can be used to generate, say a forest, around a building i created? however, it should not delete any of the blocks of the building. i want to make it look old, like the forest overran the place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WorldEdit](http://www.sk89q.com/projects/worldedit)'s [forestgen](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Generation#Forests) (both available as bukkit plugin for SMP and as SSP mod) can generate forests centred around you, but I don't know whether this will skip your house (I think it won't delete anything but you might end up with trees *on* your house, I never tried this). You'll probably have to chose at least four places a bit away from your house and generate smaller forests that don't reach your home.

Alternatively, plant some saplings manually and use bone meal to immediately grow the trees.

Comment: too bad it wont let me generate on stone, but ill manage

Comment: @calccrypto - trees cannot grow naturally on stone, though you can mine out the block beneath the tree and replace it with stone if you so desire.

Comment: i know. its just that my building happens to be very big (MCEdit says 270 chunks volume), so i was hoping to have trees "magically appear" throughout the top most layer